# A space in Link when using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, innerhtml, space

I was making a link using this

```
    s.push("<tr><td><a href=\"#\"" +'& nbsp'+ "onclick=\"changeUrl('http://url.com/m4.html?bldg=" + attribs.Number + "')\">" + attribs.MapDisplay + "</a></td></td>");

    dojo.byId("tbl").innerHTML = s.join("");
```

but out come is

```
    <a href=#
    http://url.com/m4.html#%20onclick=
    http://url.com/m4.html#&nbsponclick=%22changeUrl(%27http://url.com/m4.html?bldg=1800%27)%22
```

I've tried +'& nbsp'+ +" "+
or just space and # instead of "#" but then link gets massed up.

what should I do to make this link work fine?

Thanks,

Comment: don't use `& nbsp` or `&nbsp;` or anything like that. Just a simple space. With `innerHTML` you can add as if you would author a HTML file.

Comment: It's ok to use apostrophes instead of escaping quotes, which may be part of your issue.

Comment: I've got my answer myself like this
        s.push('<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="changeUrl(\'m4.html?bldg=' + attribs.Number + '\')">' + attribs.MapDisplay + '</a></td></tr>');

this one worked

still, not sure what was wrong with the code tho

Answer (score 2):

This is why JavaScript lets you use either `'` or `"` for quoting strings:

```
s.push('<tr><td><a href="#" onclick="changeUrl(\'http://url.com/m4.html?bldg=' + attribs.Number + '\')">' + attribs.MapDisplay + '</a></td></tr>');
//     ^--Single quotes      escape this one --^   and this one ------------------------------------^
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/uTaNadO/1/) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/uTaNadO/1/edit)

---

Side note: You have `</td></td>` at the end. I've corrected it in the above to `</td></tr>`.

Comment: Thank but also same result tho

Comment: @user2100354: No, it works: http://jsbin.com/uTaNadO/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/uTaNadO/1/edit))

Comment: maybe it's my browser problem? when I try it the link ends at # doesn't show onClick

Comment: @user2100354: You must have something slightly different. This isn't something that varies from browser to browser.

Answer (score 1):

try using "%20" when trying to make a space. Or you can even just make a regular space like you normally would.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
 s.push("<tr><td><a href='\#\' onclick=\"changeUrl('http://url.com/m4.html?bldg=" + attribs.Number + "')\">" + attribs.MapDisplay + "</a></td></td>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be overcomplicating the string a little bit. Escaping the quotation marks is unnessacary as JS allows you to use either single or double quotation marks. I broke it down and wound up with an answer similar to T.J. Crowder's but it excludes the escaped quotation marks all together.

```
s.push('<tr><td><a href="#" onclick="changeUrl("http://url.com/m4.html?bldg="' + attribs.Number + '")">' + attribs.MapDisplay + '</a></td></td>');
```

Take a look at the URL that gets output from this string and let us know how it differs from what you should have.

**edit:** is changeURL a method? I haven't seen that before and can't find anything online that pertains to it.

Comment: With the above, the `onclick` attribute will end at the `"` after `changeUrl(`.

Comment: Also: To ask the OP a question, post a comment on the question. You can't do that yet, you have to wait until you have a rep of >50, but until then just wait. Asking questions *in* answers is not how things are done here.

Comment: changeURL is just ajax function (page change without refresh )

Comment: I tried your code but still the link ends at # unfortunately I'm not sure what should I do now 0_0